# Framing with real evidence

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, verbs, transitive-verbs

Normally *to frame somebody* means

> *3 informal* produce false evidence against (an innocent person) so that they appear guilty

Now what in case of a cautious criminal who took care to hide/remove the evidence of their crimes, and now someone in the know returns the evidence to its place, replaces false records with real ones, restores removed clues etc., so that the authorities can find the criminal rightfully guilty?

Does that still count as framing?

If not, is there a name for this kind of activity?

Comment: I'd call that being *exposed*

Comment: Yeah, that's not being framed. 'Framing' means someone intentionally having an innocent (of a given crome) mistaken for the real criminal.

Comment: It's probably too rare an activity to be assigned a label. Anyone concerned to see justice prevail would probably just denounce our "cautious criminal" (he'd presumably have discovered the evidence, records and other clues in what must be "incriminating circumstances"). Either Too Localised, or NARQ

Comment: I would call this _to set up_ rather than _to frame_. (Although dictionaries like [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/set+up) don't really make that distinction, so I'm not sure.)

Comment: That guy was re-framed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for the activity is [*planting evidence*](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=planting%20evidence&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

That's an interesting distinction you draw in your question. By the way, it's only **not** framing if law enforcement is correct in their assumption about who the real purpetrator is. Unfortunately, that's not [always the case](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=evidence%20planted%20on%20innocent%20man&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Another word for planting evidence on someone innocent is [*frameup*](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=what%20is%20a%20frameup&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

[Here's an interesting discussion](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FramingTheGuiltyParty) on framing the guilty (although it's written from the perspective of television plot lines, not law enforcement, so I can't attest to its accuracy from a legal standpoint).